# caffe error with glog

Tags: segmentation-fault, caffe, glog

I have successfully installed caffe. all tests ran fine.
when i try to train an example(https://github.com/tenstep/DeepModel) using hdf5 data i get error. I read in some forum that it relates to glog.

```
*** Aborted at 1465829389 (unix time) try "date -d @1465829389" if     you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7fb5bd59d754 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0xc0) received by PID 17515 (TID 0x7fb5bf7ae780) from     PID     192; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fb5bd57fd40 (unknown)
    @     0x7fb5bd59d754 (unknown)
    @     0x7fb5bd5a6147 (unknown)
    @     0x7fb5befc9cd9 caffe::DeepHandModelLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x7fb5bf049515 caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fb5bf04a3b5 caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fb5befd472a caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7fb5befd593c caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7fb5befd5c6a caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @     0x7fb5bf02d3e3 caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
    @           0x411666 caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
    @           0x40ab20 train()
    @           0x40852c main
    @     0x7fb5bd56aec5 (unknown)
    @           0x408cfd (unknown)
    @                0x0 (unknown)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: the trace was produced by `glog` but the segmentatio fault seems to come from caffe itself. Can you post minimal example that describes your hdf5 data creation and the prototxt you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are getting a segmentation fault setting up [`DeepHandModelLayer`](https://github.com/tenstep/DeepModel/blob/master/libs/src/caffe/deep_hand_model_layers.cpp#L138). This layer is not part of caffe, but rather a "private" addition to caffe.

1. This layer reads several configuration files from folder `configuration/`. Make sure you have the required files in the right path.
2. If you still experience difficulties with this layer, you should contact its authors, as it is a very specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
::google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
```

That's all you need to suppress caffe output instead of messing the vanilla code. It took me a long while to figure this out. Click [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/99bd99795dcdf0b1d3086a8d67ab1782a8a08383/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp#L237) to check the example from caffe.